Bubblewrap not generating assetlinks.json automatically
I'm using Bubblewrap to build a Trusted Web Activity (TWA) and expected it to generate the assetlinks.json file as part of the process. However, it doesn't seem to create the file.
Indeed, I used a local keystore for signing for local debugging, but also tested using app signing from the Google Play Console. The Google documentation that says Bubblewrap should generate the assetlinks.json automatically, but it never does.
Is there a step I'm missing, or does Bubblewrap require manual creation of the assetlinks.json file?
Steps to reproduce:

Run bubblewrap init and configure the TWA project.
Use either a local keystore or Play Console app signing.
Run bubblewrap build.

The assetlinks.json file should be generated automatically according to Google ChromeOS docs, although the file is not generated.
Do you have any suggestion?

I found out, in new versions, Bubblewrap doesn't automatically generate the assetlinks.json file during the build step, even though the documentation suggests it might. I need to manually create the file using your app's signing information (SHA256) provided by Google Play (App signing page) or using keytool command on my own local keystore

As I said in the comments, I found out, in new versions, Bubblewrap doesn't automatically generate the assetlinks.json file during the build step, even though the documentation suggests it might.
Thus, I need to manually create the file using your app's signing information (SHA256) provided by Google Play (App signing page) or using keytool command on my own local keystore –
Deleter
